# VirtualBox guest doesn't boot up. I only get a black screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a problem with my Virtual box. When I try to start a guest OS, it doesn't start and I get a black screen. I tried to disable Hardware Virtualization an 3D acelaration but the only thing that changes was the black screen that started to have a white underscore blinking. I also tried to downgrade virtualBox, but it didn't work. I've tried Linux and Windows guest, but nothing changes. If it helps I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on my host machine.

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Does it really not start, or are you just saying that it does not reach login? Does it go through BIOS? Can you enter BIOS? Anyway, change the display settings and max out the available video memory.

Comment: No, the system doesn't boot up. I've done that and nothing changes

Comment: Download e.g. a Ubuntu install ISO and "insert it" as DVD/CD in the VM, boot and use the "Try it" mode to investigate the circumstances.

Comment: @ar1234a, did you find a solution to this? I've read elsewhere that the problem could be Hyper-V running in the background on Windows, but a few things that seemed to work for me were increasing base memory from 1024MB to 2048MB, increasing video memory to 128MB, and/or changing paravirtualization to minimal. Not sure which is the correct solution across the board.

Comment: Increasing video memory to 128MB worked for me.